# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django

I've been all day struggling with this issue in my starting Django Course. I'm getting this error:

> **Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P[0-9]+)/$']**

Below you can see my code. I wish someone could give me a hand on this. Thanks a lot.

views.py:

```
   from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.http import Http404
    from django.template import loader
    from .models import Question

    def index(request):
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
        print ("esto es CONTEXT: ")
        print (context)
        print(request)
        print ("FIN DE CONTEXT")
        return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
    # Create your views here.

    def detail(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

    def results(request, question_id):
        response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
        return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

    def vote(request, question_id):
        return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

index.html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Ok forget about this.... I was not including the full index.html code.... Below the correct code{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}